# Bad crossref error

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I am using TexMaker on Mac. In my BIB file, I have an item like:

```
@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/wsdm/YeungI11,
  author    = {Ching{-}man Au Yeung and
               Tomoharu Iwata},
  title     = {Strength of social influence in trust networks in product review sites},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Forth International Conference on Web Search and
               Web Data Mining, {WSDM} 2011, Hong Kong, China, February 9-12, 2011},
  pages     = {495--504},
  year      = {2011},
  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011},
  url       = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1935826.1935899},
  doi       = {10.1145/1935826.1935899},
  timestamp = {Mon, 31 Jan 2011 13:46:06 +0100},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/wsdm/YeungI11},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}
```

(I got it from DBLP website)

When I compile the TEX file, I got an error:

```
 bad cross reference---entry "DBLP:conf/wsdm/YeungI11" refers to entry "DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011", which doesn't exist
```

I can compile the file with no problem in ShareLatex.

What should I do to compile the file in TexMaker?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the entry with key `DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011` maybe missing in one bib file (the one you use with TeXmaker) but present in the bib file you use with ShareLaTeX?

Comment: Also, check if the entry with key `DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011` maybe occurs *before* the entry with key `DBLP:conf/wsdm/YeungI11`. For the `crossref` field to "work", the entry being cross-referenced has to occur after than before the entry that contains the `crossref` field.

Comment: Are you compiling with Biber or BibTeX? Can you provide a full example that can reproduce the error (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864))? As the others have pointed out you might be missing the crossref'd entry in your file. (Maybe Biber/BibTeX chokes on the special chars in the entry keys `/` might not be good, though I would have thought they work.)

Answer (score 7):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I can think of two reasons for why you're getting the following error message

> bad cross reference---entry "DBLP:conf/wsdm/YeungI11" refers to entry "DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011", which doesn't exist

First, the entry with key `DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011` is missing in the bib file you use on your local machine (with TeXMaker as the front end). Second, the entry is actually present in the bib file, but it occurs *before* the entry with key `DBLP:conf/wsdm/YeungI11`. For BibTeX's `crossref` field to work, the entry being cross-referenced *must* occur later in the bib file than the entry that contains the `crossref` field in question.

At any rate, the following MWE works fine (information for both entries obtained from DBLP); note the ordering of the entries in `test.bib`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@inproceedings{DBLP:conf/wsdm/YeungI11,
  author    = {Ching{-}man Au Yeung and
               Tomoharu Iwata},
  title     = {Strength of social influence in trust networks in product review sites},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Forth International Conference on Web Search and
               Web Data Mining, {WSDM} 2011, Hong Kong, China, February 9-12, 2011},
  pages     = {495--504},
  year      = {2011},
  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011},
  url       = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1935826.1935899},
  doi       = {10.1145/1935826.1935899},
  timestamp = {Mon, 31 Jan 2011 13:46:06 +0100},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/wsdm/YeungI11},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}

@proceedings{DBLP:conf/wsdm/2011,
  editor    = {Irwin King and
               Wolfgang Nejdl and
               Hang Li},
  title     = {Proceedings of the Forth International Conference on Web Search and
               Web Data Mining, {WSDM} 2011, Hong Kong, China, February 9-12, 2011},
  publisher = {{ACM}},
  year      = {2011},
  isbn      = {978-1-4503-0493-1},
  timestamp = {Mon, 31 Jan 2011 13:29:32 +0100},
  biburl    = {http://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bib/conf/wsdm/2011},
  bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, http://dblp.org}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{DBLP:conf/wsdm/YeungI11}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```